# php-ews: Access shared calendars?

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

Using php-ews: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

I'm able to list events from my own calendar according to this example: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Calendar:-Get-List-(Retrieving-Id-and-ChangeKey) But after searching for a solution for a few hours I still haven't been able to find a way to access shared calendars.

This question is similar, but has no answer: [EWS: Access shared calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217527/ews-access-shared-calendars)

From looking at that and various other search results (I've googled many variants of "ews shared calendar") I have to find the location of the shared calendar, get the id and then use that. But I haven't been able to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Look into the account permissions for the exchange account you are using.  I know that you can use the impersonation route if the account has impersonation privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code block under *Only look in the "calendars folder"* add this in order to retrieve events from email@address.com's calendar:

```
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox = new StdClass;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox->EmailAddress = 'email@address.com';
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Would recommend @L42 accepts this answer.