# php-ews Access all calendars including shared

Tags: php, calendar, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I have a calendar for a conference room shared with me. What I am hoping to do is to use php-ews to pull that calendar schedule for display. So far, I have been able to easily display my OWN calendar without issue. This was done using the code at: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Calendar:-Get-List-(Retrieving-Id-and-ChangeKey)

I saw on a similar question ([php-ews: Access shared calendars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609527/php-ews-access-shared-calendars)) someone suggesting adding these lines in the "Only look in the calendars folder" section:

```
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox = new StdClass;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox->EmailAddress = 'email@address.com';
```

This didn't break the code or anything, but it also didn't change the results. I was still only given my own calendar as a result. I have seen mention of impersonation as one method, but since the calendar is shared with me already I don't think that should be necessary. Is there something I have overlooked? I do have the identity path of the calendar, which is (replacing identifying details with words in CAPS): 
    DOMAIN.com/OU/USERNAME:\calendar\NAME OF CALENDAR

I hope this is enough to help solve the problem. There are a couple questions on stack overflow dealing with this (but without answers that solved my issue), so if we get it sorted I will be sure to pass on the solution to those locations as well.

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'email@address.com' needs to be the primary SMTP address of the conference room. If you're already doing that, it would be helpful to see the full SOAP request that gets sent to the server.

Comment: I asked my IT department the address for that room (as I don't have access to the management console directly) and they said: 
"As far as I know a shared calendar does not have an address other than the owner."
Would there be any way for me to get the SMTP address of the calendar other than with the management console?

Comment: You could log on to Outlook Web App and look in the address book. For example, for me, on Exchange 2013, I go to "People" at the top, then expand "Directory", and select "All Rooms". You should see the email address for it there. They are right that the shared calendar does not have an SMTP address, just the owner of that shared calendar, which in this case, is the conference room. (Unless I'm totally not understanding your scenario :))

Comment: Can't find it in the directory, I am fairly sure that my organization doesn't create the rooms through exchange, and that they are instead created by the users at the outlook level. Looking at the properties for the shared calendar, the type is showing as "Folder containing calendar items". I am betting this makes a difference, so I will be going down that path of inquiry next. Thanks for your help so far, Jason.

Comment: So to clarify, this is basically a secondary calendar in a user's mailbox? I'm not real clear on the scenario here. Is it UserB has a secondary calendar shared with UserA?